# Send SMS to each number in Django Database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, twilio

Having trouble sending an SMS with python/django/twilio to employees in a table where each employee has an "admin" relationship

Table Employees contains:
fname, lname, phone_number, group

## views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient('xx...', 'xxx...')
            recipients = employees.objects.filter(group__contains='admin')
            for number in recipients:
                client.messages.create(body='Sample text',to=number, from_='xxxxxx')
        
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form':form})
```

The 'recipients'.... line in my code seems to be the culprit.  I am getting an error message for the 'number' value in the client.messages.create line: ValueError: data should be an integer, binary, or string, or sequence.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models


class employees(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15) 
    group = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `for number in recipients`, number is an object not a phone number. You need to do:

```
client.messages.create(body='Sample text', to=number.phone_number, from_='xxxxxx')
```

You can rename `number` to `recipient` so that it can be:

```
for recipient in recipients:
    client.messages.create(body='Sample text', to=recipient.phone_number, from_='xxxxxx')
```